# paypal login button not functioning in express checkout

Tags: angular, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm writing an angular6 e-commerce application and I'm trying to implement paypal express checkout into it.

I created a sandbox in my business account and created a client access token to be used with it.

I tried using both the the `ngx-paypal` module from https://github.com/Enngage/ngx-paypal

and I also tried to implement it myself using the tutorial at http://tphangout.com/angular-5-paypal-express-checkout/

both of them provides the same results.

[image: paypal express checkout popup]

the PayPal express checkout popup shows up, but the "Log In to PayPal" button is not functioning. when I click on it nothing happens.

I tried to look into chrome developers console and this is what I see:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
```

for the url

```
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/hermes/api/batch/setbuyer
```

any ideas ?

thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the buyer account in the sandbox developer site to be able to pay.